# Excel macro runs Access macro issue

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I have an Excel macro that imports files into an Access database.  The Excel macro uses a shell command to open Access and kick off a macro in the Access database.  The Access macro runs an Access VBA function that runs several routines in Access.  This works for me.  I'm located in the US.

A UK user tries to run the Excel macro.  Access opens but displays an error message.  The Access database is located on the UK server.

I remoted in to the user's machine and opened the Access database.  I then selected "macros" and pushed the "run macro" icon.  A pop-up displayed and showed the macro name.  You had to click "Ok" or "cancel".  I've never seen this before and was wondering if this is the reason that the UK user gets the error message.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  thanks...........

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the settings of his Access. If all fails, download and use this program called Express ClickYes. It automatically clicks yes when message boxes in Access pops up

Comment: ...........Any particular setting I should check.  The one that stood out to me was under Object Designers > Query designs:  The user's permissions was checked instead of the owner's.  Would this make a difference?  Thanks for the help....

Comment: I'm not sure, but it maybe worth the try.

Comment: And why don't you try running the macro from the command prompt instead of opening it via excel. For example, this is how I open my macro on the command line:-


["\\DiskStation\database\Support Files\Front Ends\ENPG_Development_Ver10.accdb" /x autoemail]

Name of your database.extension /x macroname

You could save it as a batch file and run it via windows task scheduler if needed. Or simply double click the batchfile to run

Comment: ..........Thanks.  SInce I'm in the US and the user was in the UK, it is difficult to troubleshoot since the Excel macro works for me.  I created some instructions for the user to open the database and select the appropriate macro and run it.  So far so good.  Thanks for the information.  I appreciate your help